# How do I add autofill options under a UITextField for ios App?

Tags: ios

I'd like to add these convenient [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayCgNm.png) autofill completion options to my iOS app:

[image]

What I'm doing is using Walmart's API to select an item, so if a user types "che", I'd like there to be three options under the UITextField such as "cheezits", "cheddar cheese", and "chewing gum" for example. I understand how to use APIs, so I'm really just trying to figure out the best way to display these options. My only guess is to use a collectionview that stays hidden unless `textField.text != nil`... is this the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a collectionview which is initially hidden. I did this once using a collection view which was initially hidden provided the constraints are properly setup. And whenever user types in a place name, the collection view was populated by using Google places sdk.